# How to set attribute on widget in flask-wtf?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am using a TextArea provided by Flask-WTF.

```
numbers = forms.TextField('Numbers', [forms.validators.Required()], widget=forms.widgets.TextArea())
```

I want to change cols of the resulting fields to say 80. How do I accomplish this. I don't want to do it in template and would like to do this in form.

Django provides:

```
name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Your name',})
```

I want something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it during output in your html

like: form.numbers(cols=20)

Oh, sorry did not notice that you mentioned template.

Update: 
Actualy also had this problem, my solution was to extend Form class and add dictionary to form objects.
So all custom attributes go into that dictionary and used on output. This can be done with custom template macros or redefining render methods